# C++ Destructor runs twice

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, clang, destructor

See the program below. The program should print 1 as 1 counter object still exists, but when compiled with GCC, it prints 0. Why is that? Is this a compiler bug? This only occurs when returning from a different scope. Removing the if completely fixes it on all compilers.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int counter = 0;

class Counter {
public:
    Counter() {
        counter++;
    }
    ~Counter() {
        counter--;
    }
};

Counter test() {
    if (true) { // REMOVING THIS FIXES IT
        Counter c;
        return c;
    } else {
        throw std::logic_error("Impossible!");
    }
}

int main() {
    Counter c = test();
    std::cout << counter << std::endl; // 0 on GCC (incorrect), 1 on clang (correct)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The other compiler generated constructors are not doing the `counter++`, which will throw the counts off.

Comment: put cout in the constructor and destructor

Comment: @Eljay Why does the if statement change the result?

Comment: Probably because of copy elision, or NRVO.  *shrug*

Comment: @BlueCannonBall *Is this a compiler bug?* -- The compiler you're using is used by thousands of people around the world, and thousands of companies around the world.   The applications developed using this compiler go from very simple to very complex.  Game engines, end-user applications, operating systems, embedded systems you use now in many devices, etc.  Given that, do you think it is reasonable to even suspect a "compiler bug", given how simple your code is?

Comment: @BlueCannonBall `// 0 on GCC (incorrect), 1 on clang (correct)` --  They both are "correct".

Comment: @BlueCannonBall *C++ Destructor runs twice* -- If you had done this in the destructor: `~Counter() {
        counter--; std::cout << "The object destroyed is: " << this << "\n"; }` -- you would have gotten a better picture of what is happening.  You would have seen that different objects were being destroyed, and not the same object being destroyed twice.

Comment: The thing about compiler bugs is what are you going to do about it if you find one? I 
 a real-world production environment you probably can't switch compilers unless you're really early in a project. You can't sit back and wait for it to be fixed. Can you imagine the conversation with the management? "Sorry boss. Project is on hold for a few moths until the patch comes out. A year, tops."  When you do find a compiler bug, and sooner or later you'll find at least one, usually the best you can do is understand it and work around it.

Comment: The reason is that there are constructors being called (copy or move of temporaries) that don't increment `count`.   You haven't actually specified what C++ standard you are compiling with (and the standard supported by default varies with version of each compiler).  Elision of temporaries is optional with older C++ standards (so compiling code for an older standard can give different behaviours of your code even without changing compiler, depending on chosen optimisation settings) and only mandatory (in specified circumstances) in recent standards (C++17 and later).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++ returning an object from a function copy-constructs the object in the caller's context, then destroys the copied-from object, in the function being returned from. In some circumstances this copy can be elided.

```
       Counter c;
       return c;
```

This is named return value optimization and it is not mandatory in this case. Copy elision here is allowed, but it's optional. One of the compilers you used elides this copy, the other does not.

Without copy elision the compiler copy-constructs the returned object in the caller's context.

This `Counter` lacks a copy constructor, so the shown code fails to log an instance of the copy-constructed object.

Simply add a copy constructor:

```
class Counter {
public:
    Counter() {
        counter++;
    }
    Counter(const Counter &) {
        counter++;
    }
    ~Counter() {
        counter--;
    }
};
```

Now, you'll get the expected result, with or without copy elision.

If you set a breakpoint in the copy-constructor you'll see the breakpoint hit when returning from the function (when using the compiler that does not elide the copy).

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that adding `-fno-elide-constructors` when compiling will give consistent results on both compilers. It's another way of seeing what's going on.

Answer (score -7):

The `destructor` is called at the end of the scope that has had objects in.

1. When the first line - in `main` - excited, it will call `test()`.
2. As you have put the condition true, it will create an object, which
   will increase `counter` by one.
3. It will `return c`, but on the other hand, it's the end of the
   scope, which means that the `destructor` will be called, thus
   `counter--`.

To be honest, I am not sure about my answer, but I think that what it is.